# How on filamentphp site with custom register to move to profile page?

Tags: laravel, laravel-filament

On laravel 10 / filamentphp 3 site with multi tenancy I made custom register page with additive columns and code in app/Providers/Filament/AppPanelProvider.php :

```
 <?php

 namespace App\Providers\Filament;

 use App\Filament\App\Pages\Auth\Register; // I define custom Register page
 use App\Filament\App\Pages\Tenancy\RegisterBranch;
 use App\Models\Branch;
 use Filament\PanelProvider;
 ...
 class AppPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
 {
     public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
     {
         return $panel
             ->default()
             ->plugins([ ])
             ->id('app')
             ->path('app')
             ->login()
             ->profile()
             ->registration(Register::class)
```

I define custom Register page as I need with creating User model to add 2 additive models  and in app/Filament/Pages/Auth/MyCustomRegister.php I call aditive event :

```
<?php

namespace App\Filament\Pages\Auth;

use App\Events\UserRegisteredEvent;
use DanHarrin\LivewireRateLimiting\Exceptions\TooManyRequestsException;
use Filament\Facades\Filament;
use Filament\Forms\Form;
use Filament\Http\Responses\Auth\Contracts\RegistrationResponse;
use Filament\Notifications\Notification;
use Filament\Pages\Auth\Register;

/**
 * @property Form $form
 */
class MyCustomRegister extends Register // SimplePage
{

    public function register(): ?RegistrationResponse
    {
        try {
            $this->rateLimit(2);
        } catch (TooManyRequestsException $exception) {
            Notification::make()
                ->title(__('filament-panels::pages/auth/register.notifications.throttled.title', [
                    'seconds' => $exception->secondsUntilAvailable,
                    'minutes' => ceil($exception->secondsUntilAvailable / 60),
                ]))
                ->body(array_key_exists('body', __('filament-panels::pages/auth/register.notifications.throttled') ?: []) ? __('filament-panels::pages/auth/register.notifications.throttled.body', [
                    'seconds' => $exception->secondsUntilAvailable,
                    'minutes' => ceil($exception->secondsUntilAvailable / 60),
                ]) : null)
                ->danger()
                ->send();

            return null;
        }

        $data = $this->form->getState();

        $user = $this->getUserModel()::create($data);

        $this->sendEmailVerificationNotification($user);

        Filament::auth()->login($user);

        session()->regenerate();

        $request= request();
        UserRegisteredEvent::dispatch($user, $this->data); // I call event to add more models

        // if to uncomment line below I got error that RegistrationResponse must be returned
//        return redirect()->route('filament.app.auth.profile')->with('message', $user->name . ' was registered !');
        return app(RegistrationResponse::class);
    }
}
```

But page for entering of new tenant "app/new" is opened. I routes I found lines:

```
       GET|HEAD  app/new ........................................................................................................... filament.app.tenant.registration › App\Filament\App\Pages\Tenancy\RegisterBranch

       GET|HEAD  app/profile ............................................................................................................................... filament.app.auth.profile › Filament\Pages › EditProfile
```

to move to profile page

In filamentphp docs I did not find any RegistrationResponse reference, which is in vendor/filament/filament/src/Http/Responses/Auth/Contracts/RegistrationResponse.php file :

```
namespace Filament\Http\Responses\Auth\Contracts;

use Illuminate\Contracts\Support\Responsable;

interface RegistrationResponse extends Responsable
{
}
```

Have I declare RegistrationResponse with redirect to 'filament.app.auth.profile' ? How ?
Or in some other way ?

```
"laravel/framework": "^10.28.0",
"filament/filament": "^3.0-stable",
```

**DETAILS BLOCK :**
With command

```
php artisan vendor:publish --tag=filament-config
```

I created file config/filament.php:

```
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Broadcasting
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | By uncommenting the Laravel Echo configuration, you may connect Filament
    | to any Pusher-compatible websockets server.
    |
    | This will allow your users to receive real-time notifications.
    |
    */

    'broadcasting' => [

        // 'echo' => [
        //     'broadcaster' => 'pusher',
        //     'key' => env('VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY'),
        //     'cluster' => env('VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER'),
        //     'wsHost' => env('VITE_PUSHER_HOST'),
        //     'wsPort' => env('VITE_PUSHER_PORT'),
        //     'wssPort' => env('VITE_PUSHER_PORT'),
        //     'authEndpoint' => '/api/v1/broadcasting/auth',
        //     'disableStats' => true,
        //     'encrypted' => true,
        // ],

    ],

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Default Filesystem Disk
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the storage disk Filament will use to put media. You may use any
    | of the disks defined in the `config/filesystems.php`.
    |
    */

    'default_filesystem_disk' => env('FILAMENT_FILESYSTEM_DISK', 'public'),

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Assets Path
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This is the directory where Filament's assets will be published to. It
    | is relative to the `public` directory of your Laravel application.
    |
    | After changing the path, you should run `php artisan filament:assets`.
    |
    */

    'assets_path' => null,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Livewire Loading Delay
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This sets the delay before loading indicators appear.
    |
    | Setting this to 'none' makes indicators appear immediately, which can be
    | desirable for high-latency connections. Setting it to 'default' applies
    | Livewire's standard 200ms delay.
    |
    */

    'livewire_loading_delay' => 'default',

];
```

which have the only commented "authEndpoint" parameter.
Looking at the branch I tried to add lines :

```
    'auth' => [
        'pages' => [
//            'login' => \Your\Custom\LoginLogic::class,
            'register' => \Your\Custom\RegisterLogic::class,
        ],
    ],
```

What must in in RegisterLogic - as I need to relpace After Register method with my code ?

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 1):

For Overriding Register Page, We Need to Create a New Page as Below

`php artisan make:filament-page Auth/Register`

The Register Page Should be then Modifies as Below:

`app/Filament/Pages/Auth/Register.php`

```
use Filament\Pages\Auth\Register as BaseRegister;

class Register extends BaseRegister {}
```

Then in `app/Providers/Filament/AdminPanelProvider.php`

```
use App\Filament\Pages\Auth\Register;

class AdminPanelProvider extends PanelProvider
{
  public function panel(Panel $panel): Panel
  {
     return $panel
        ->default()
        ->id('admin')
        ->path('admin')
        ->login()
        ->registration(Register::class)
        //....
  }
}
```

Now You Can Add your Custom Fields Here as in Below Example. Everything will be handled by the Filament unless you are using custom Database model to For Registration For that you can Follow up This [Link](https://medium.com/@josephajibodu/change-laravel-authentication-model-for-filamentphp-3-b69fa1560cb2)

```
use Filament\Forms\Components\Select;
use Filament\Forms\Components\Component;
 
class Register extends BaseRegister
{
    protected function getForms(): array
    {
        return [
            'form' => $this->form(
                $this->makeForm()
                    ->schema([
                        $this->getNameFormComponent(),
                        $this->getEmailFormComponent(),
                        $this->getPasswordFormComponent(),
                        $this->getPasswordConfirmationFormComponent(),
                        $this->getRoleFormComponent(), 
                    ])
                    ->statePath('data'),
            ),
        ];
    }
 
    protected function getRoleFormComponent(): Component
    {
        return Select::make('role')
            ->options([
                'buyer' => 'Buyer',
                'seller' => 'Seller',
            ])
            ->default('buyer')
            ->required();
    }
}
```

Comment: filament3 has no app/config/filament.php file. Many options can be set in app/Providers/Filament/AdminPanelProvider.php file. I think I need somehow to catch event on Registration oser a user and make redirect I need.

Comment: Thanks for provided links!
Please read DETAILS BLOCK :

Comment: Mark it as an Answer if the issue as been solved @PetroGromovo

Comment: on the link you provided I did not how to salve my issue. Please read DETAILS BLOCK

Comment: Now Make the Fix, I think this will solve your problem

Comment: No , from the start my question was how 
in my custom RegistrationResponse.php to define url to profile page(define custom url).
I know how to register Custom Registration class...